# Change specific parameter of URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, url-encoding, urldecode

I've `node application` and I'm getting the following URL (in req.header. of express)
I need to change the port number(of the *redirect url*) e.g. from `77777` to `88888`,

I tried with *parse encode and decode* without success but maybe I miss something,

I need to use the standard (parse encode and decode) way and *not just replace*...(which works)

Any idea how to do that? I need at the end after I change this URL to keep it in **exactly** the same format (After encod/decode...) as follows.

http://gr-t6fa45e73.go.grp.corp:54001/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fro-d3ma32e85.mo.grp.corp%3A77777%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=zs6.node

Comment: You have asked this already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [url](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html)

```
var URL ="http://gr-t6fa45e73.go.grp.corp:54001/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fro-d3ma32e85.mo.grp.corp%3A77777%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=zs6.node";

var parts = URL.split("redirect_uri="),    
decoded = decodeURIComponent(parts[1])),
red = url.parse(decoded);
red.port=88888;
URL = parts[0]+"redirect_uri="+encodeURIComponent(url.format(red));
```

**UPDATE** Using this version of [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js)

I use .build instead of .format.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/86yv6e6b/)

Result:

> http://gr-t6fa45e73.go.grp.corp:54001/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fro-d3ma32e85.mo.grp.corp%3A88888%2Flogin%2Fcallback%26client_id%3Dzs6.node

Comment: Thanks but I try it out and its not working, currently two problems 1. the port was not changed!,2. at the end of the url I got callback%26client_id%3Dzs6. and I need to get it as before callback&client_id=zs6.node ,any idea?

Comment: Can you log what is changed? I do not do any Node coding myself and I just found the url plugin at the node.js site but have no node server to test it. FWIW The redirectURL is not a valid encoded URL if it has & in it before decoding

Comment: Thanks but for me if you copy this URL and provide a solution in JSFiddle with JS its sufficient, the node its not a big parameter here ? the logic to change the port and to return back the URL to the starting point(As i put in the post) with just the port that was changed this is the issue here...

Comment: And why can't you use simple replace?

Comment: Since as I write in the post I try to find some standard way to do that ? you dont think that it possible?

Comment: Yes, as I posted, but since your URL is not conforming to standard since it is not proper escaped, then there is no standard way to do what you want